# Xamarin Android app crashes in release mode (default constructor not found)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin app here that runs in debug mode without any problems, but in release mode it crashes instantly saying that a default constructor for one of my pages is missing.

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type PraxisApp.MasterPage occurred
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why this happens in Release mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely due to the fact that it is being stripped by the Mono Linker:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Add a PreserveAttribute to the top of your Page class:

```
[Preserve (AllMembers = true)]
public class MasterPage
{
   ~~~
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'PraxisApp.MasterPage;' to your Ignore assemblies (ProjectSettings -> Android Build -> Linker)